# Is this an integrated crown race?

Tags: headset, bearings, stem, steering, crownrace

The title says it all. I would like to change the bearings for my headset,but i have no idea if this crown race is removable.

It is a Bontrager fork, probably from 2007.

Thank you,

From Norway.
[image]

Comment: By "change" your bearings, do you mean replace with identical new ones, or do you mean change to a different headset? If keeping the same headset, you should not need to change the fork crown race.

Comment: I don’t think it’s integrated. A clue is the machined area on the steerer, which allows for a “precise” press fit of the crown race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, and it doesn't look like it. Integrated crown races on road bikes are usually found on all-carbon forks and they were also nascent then if they existed at all. Also, the part indicated by the arrow looks an awful lot like the split of a crown race that slides on:
[image: crown race]

If it's not a slip on type and is simply a difficult to remove one with no overhang, there are shop tools that can do that. And as mentioned in the comments, if all you need is bearings, hopefully you can get replacements and not have to mess with the crown race or replacing the whole headset.

Comment: OK thank you very much for your thorough answer! You're right it is removable. I am changing bearings, but to a different brand.